# How to store mp3 files in harddisk and maintain performance

Tags: c#, search, filesystems

I'm working on a project which will have millions of small mp3 files that I was thinking to save in harddisk.

I have the following questions:

- What is the structure I should use to save the files? one folder or
  many folders.
- what is the best way to Searching ?

Comment: This feels hugely open-ended - "design my software for me", and "best" depends on a massive number of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do a similar thing on a project that involved storing a large number of images. Using some meta data for the file, I generated an MD5 hash which I then used as the file name. The first character of the filename would be the grandparent directory for the file, and the second character the parent. Resulting in a file structure like this:

[image]

This has the advantage of keeping the files evenly distributed over the directories. And if you pick the metadata used to generate the hash well, then it also has the advantage of being able to find a file without using a database to store references to it.

I've found this method to work pretty well with 100k or so files, but without more information of what exactly you're trying to do it's hard to know if it's appropriate for your problem...

Answer (score 2):

The best approach might be to store the information you are going to search on in a database and use that to search on. You can then use something like Lucene or Solr to do the searching.

The database would store a reference to the file on disk and just use that directly when the search pops out it's results. This means you can organise the files on disk in any order you like.

However, without a lot more information this is effectively just a guess.